# Error when passing an object to a javascript funtion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I define this variable:

```
    var data={
        cliente:cliente
        ubicacion:ubicacion
    };
```

(cliente and ubicacion are already defined variables)

and pass it as such to the function:

```
        app.save($('#sector').val(),{ //funcion que llama al save del api
            data
        });
```

this is the function:

```
save : function(sector,data){ //api call save
    console.log(data.cliente);
```

I get an error saying data.cliente is undefined

Comment: You want to pass `data` instead of `{ data }` as the second argument.

Comment: Try `data.data.cliente` and report back.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you!

Comment: Or simply `app.save($('#sector').val(), data);` - Without the curly braces around `data`. It already is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the braces :

```
save : function(sector,{data}){ //api call save
    console.log(data.cliente);
```